# Password encryption on -ZAP

Tags: zap

I have a problem while running the scan on ZAP.
In our application they use some encryption for password at the time of application.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP874.png)
when i run the scan in ZAP password is not getting encrypted.refer below screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gELkG.png)

how can we use the algorithm in zap which we are using in our application
If some one can help me on this soon it will be greate
thank you

Comment: What's controllers.py? That doesn't seem like a ZAP component.

Comment: Yeah - is this anything to do with OWASP ZAP? If not you might want to be more specific, and not use the 'zap' tag which is just for OWASP ZAP :)